# Unable to set nodejs path in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, appium

I have to run Appium automation project on Jenkins server, for that need to add Nodejs path.
Unable to set Nodejs path in Jenkins, as not found the Nodejs option in **Global Tool Configuration** settings, please have a look the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're specifically looking for the auto-installer/global tool configuration, you need to install the [NodeJS Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin) by going to `http://JENKINS_URL/pluginManager/available` and filtering for `nodejs`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the nodejs path is an Environment variable, you can try using: https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject